# Adding reminder entry in Google Calendar

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, google-calendar-api

I want to add reminder in `Google Calendar`. To do that I am referring this article

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet

but as soon as my debugger reach

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
```

nothing heppens. Application halts and nothing printed on console.

Full Code: I have converted it to vb code as I need to use it in VB.Net app

```
Sub Main()
        Dim Scopes As String() = {CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly}
        Dim ApplicationName As String = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart"
        Dim credential As UserCredential
        Using stream = New FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Dim clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets
            Dim credPath As String = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, "D:/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json")
            Dim dataStore = New FileDataStore(credPath, True)
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(clientSecrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, dataStore).Result
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " & credPath)
        End Using

        Dim service = New CalendarService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = credential, .ApplicationName = ApplicationName})
        Dim request As EventsResource.ListRequest = service.Events.List("primary")
        request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now
        request.ShowDeleted = False
        request.SingleEvents = True
        request.MaxResults = 10
        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime
        Dim events As Events = request.Execute()
        Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:")
        If events.Items IsNot Nothing AndAlso events.Items.Count > 0 Then
            For Each eventItem In events.Items
                Dim [when] As String = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString()
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty([when]) Then
                    [when] = eventItem.Start.Date
                End If

                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, [when])
            Next
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.")
        End If

        Console.Read()
    End Sub
```

Comment: please post your full code that isn't enough to reproduce the problem

Comment: @DaImTo I have added comeplete code

Answer (score 0):

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
```

Is just authencating your application to Google.  The first time it ran it should have prompted you for permissions to access your account for the scopes you requested.   You can find a file in credPath contain the credentials.

You may want to add a Console.Readline(); so that your console application stops and you can see what is there.

I have some more sample code here that might help [Google calendar .net](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3)

Comment: I already added Console.Read() at the end as mention in the link. Console is still blank.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my default browser from Firefox to Google Chrome and it work. May be I should report this bug to Firefox.